# How to populate Setters={} with an array of Style using Markup Extension syntax?

Tags: c#, maui

I want to avoid writing deeply nested xml expressions so I want to convert the first `Label` (from Microsoft's tutorial) to the second one (my version) using curly-braced markup extension syntax.

I have no idea how to set an array of `Style` to `Setters`. So far I cannot find an example.

```cs
public class BoolToObject<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public T TrueObject { get; set; } = default(T)!;
    public T FalseObject { get; set; } = default(T)!;

    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is true ? TrueObject : FalseObject;
    }

    public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is not null)
            return ((T)value).Equals(TrueObject);
        else
            return null;
    }
}

public class BoolToStyle : BoolToObject<Style>;
```

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Switch x:Name="switch" />
    <Label FontSize="18" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label.Style>
            <Binding Source="{x:Reference switch}"
                        Path="IsToggled">
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <local:BoolToObject x:TypeArguments="Style">
                        <local:BoolToObject.TrueObject>
                            <Style TargetType="Label">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Indubitably!" />
                                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic, Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
                            </Style>
                        </local:BoolToObject.TrueObject>

                        <local:BoolToObject.FalseObject>
                            <Style TargetType="Label">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Maybe later" />
                                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None" />
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
                            </Style>
                        </local:BoolToObject.FalseObject>
                    </local:BoolToObject>
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
    <Label FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Center"
            Style="{Binding IsToggled, Source={Reference switch}, 
                    Converter={
                        local:BoolToStyle, 
                        TrueObject={Style TargetType=Label, Setters={}},
                        FalseObject={}                
                    }}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Last, is `x:Reference` and `Reference` interchangeable? Both work I think.

Comment: In your example, it is not clear your multiple Style use case, since the two styles you provided cannot be merged. Also, with the Converter provided it's not clear where the array parameter is. However, I provided a DataTrigger answer as an alternative answer which you may find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your XAML syntax problem is to be aware of the fact that the `Setters` are given as a ContentProperty which means the array may come first with the attribute name being implicit. However, even with this fact the program will fail with an exception.

```xml
<Label
    FontSize="20"
    Style="{Binding IsToggled, Source={Reference switch}, Converter={local:BoolToStyle
    TrueObject={Style {Setter Property='Text', Value='Indubitably!'}, {Setter Property='FontAttributes', Value='Italic,Bold'}, {Setter Property='TextColor', Value='Green'}, TargetType='Label' },
    FalseObject={Style {Setter Property='Text', Value='Maybe later'}, {Setter Property='FontAttributes', Value='None'}, {Setter Property='TextColor', Value='Red'}, TargetType='Label'}}}"
    VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

Some interesting points that may lead you to an alternative solution to your problem are:

1. It's highly recommended to store Style and Converters in a ResourceDictionary so that you can refer to them later
2. Rather than code your own BoolToObject converter, you should consider using the CommunityToolkit.Maui BoolToObjectConverter instead
3. Also, instead of the BoolToObject converter, your use-case can be implemented with no code-behind by using DataTrigger instead

Here's a demonstration of all of the above:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="your_class_goes_here"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">

    <!--#region ResourceDictionary-->
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="style1" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Indubitably!" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic, Bold" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="style2" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Maybe later" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
            <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter
                x:Key="BoolToStyleConverter"
                FalseObject="{StaticResource style2}"
                TrueObject="{StaticResource style1}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout.Resources />
            <Switch x:Name="switch" />
            <!--#region CommunityToolkit version-->
            <Label FontSize="20" Style="{Binding IsToggled, Source={Reference switch}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStyleConverter}}" />
            <!--#endregion-->
            <!--#region DataTrigger version-->
            <Label
                FontSize="20"
                Style="{StaticResource style1}"
                VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding IsToggled, Source={Reference switch}}"
                        TargetType="Label"
                        Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource style2}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
            <!--#endregion  -->
            <!--#region inline Converter-->
            <Label
                FontSize="20"
                Style="{Binding IsToggled, Source={Reference switch}, Converter={toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter TrueObject={StaticResource style1}, FalseObject={StaticResource style2}}}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <!--#endregion-->
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.datatrigger?view=net-maui-8.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/bool-to-object-converter
- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/d03a2c66aa22b8a76eb3adec4235d17f917adf5f/src/Controls/src/Core/Style.cs#L10

Comment: What are official names for these syntaxes `<loc:xyz>...</loc:xyz>` and `{loc:xyz ...}`?

Comment: Whilst, typically Maui components can be expressed in extended form or as a markup extension, Microsoft made effort to come up with this equivalency (e.g. `<MultiBinding ...>` and `{MultiBinding ...}`, but there is no guaranteed that is the case. Therefore, your own component, if you wish to offer it up as a markup extension, you will have to make the effort to code it as such to meet your parity or non-parity needs, but, it is a different implementation.